# Any best way to store two vales against one Id/Index

Tags: powershell, indexing, collections, key-value

Here I just want to get suggestion from experts at this forum:

In Poweshell, I have a requirement where i want to store two different values against one index. Because later i want to access those two values against unique index somthing like that in Powershell:

```
at index 0 = [value1,valu2]
at index 1 = [value3,valu4]
at index 2 = [value5,valu6]
```

and so on...

What is the best approach available to do that in powershell?

Comment: Use an array, or hashtable, or custom object.

Comment: Is there any type of array that can store two values at one index? Is there any example

Comment: An array of arrays, or an array of hashtables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is indexed by number. The value can be any object (including another array).

```
$a = @(
    @('val1', 'val2') ,
    @(1234, 5678) ,
    @(321, 'val6')
)

$a[0][0]  # 'val1'
$a[0][1]  # 'val2'
$a[2][0]  # 321
```

To use `.Add()` and `.Remove()` methods, consider a `[hashtable]` (this one has arrays as values):

```
$a = @{
    0 = @('val1', 'val2')
    1 = @(1234, 5678)
    2 = @(321, 'val6')
}

$a.Add(3, @('valX','valY'))

$a[0][0]  # 'val1'
$a[0][1]  # 'val2'
$a[2][0]  # 321
```

The values themselves could be hashtables as well, if you want to use the methods on them too.

Comment: Instead of array, is there any other collection avaiable, where i can use builtin add/remove methods like we use in Arraylist?

Comment: Dictionary vs Hashtable, which one is more good in powershell regarding performance?

Comment: @SPBeginer I'm not sure what you mean by dictionary. If it's array vs hashtable, i would guess array. In any case you could do your own test run with `Measure-Command -Expression { <# code to test here #> }`

Comment: i mean Dictionary object

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness you can also use custom PowerShell objects. I am using the same sample data set that briantist used.

```
$a = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{Index1 = 'val1';Index2 = 'val2'},
    [pscustomobject]@{Index1 = '1234';Index2 = '5678'},
    [pscustomobject]@{Index1 = '321';Index2 = 'val6'}
)

$a[2].Index1
321
```

This requires 3.0 but you can change this easy for 2.0

If you already have a collection of arrays then you can just use the same logic in a loop

```
$a = @(
    @('val1', 'val2') ,
    @(1234, 5678) ,
    @(321, 'val6')
) | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{Index1 = $_[0];Index2 = $_[1]}
}
```